openCypher complex path pattern support
I wonder if there is regex-like path pattern support for more complex path queries in openCypher. Here are some examples:

A path with alternative relationships, like Follows-Likes-Follows-Likes-...
It is supposed to be written like:
MATCH path = ( startUser : User { name : ' Adam '})-[: (Follows·Likes)* ] - >( endUser : User )
RETURN path

A path with multiple relationships between nodes, like Follows&Likes-Follows&Likes...
It is supposed to be written like:
MATCH path = ( startUser : User { name : ' Adam '})-[: (Follows&Likes)* ] - >( endUser : User )
RETURN path

A path with mixed relationships and one of them is limited to occur at certain times, like Follows-Likes with multiple Follows but only 5 Likes.
It is supposed to be written like:
MATCH path = ( startUser : User { name : ' Adam '})-[: Follows*|Likes*5] - >( endUser : User )
RETURN path

A path with mixed relationships and one of them is limited to occur at positions, like a Follows-Likes chain ended by 5 Likes.
It is supposed to be written like:
MATCH path = ( startUser : User { name : ' Adam '})-[: Follows*·Likes*5] - >( endUser : User )
RETURN path


What I know is that openCypher supports Follows* and (Follows|Knows)*, but it doesn't support conjunction. Does that mean it does not support complex expressions when querying paths? Because it seems to only select from one or a set of relationships but does not have any order or count control over the path with multiple relationships.

For general documentation I think this is a good place to start https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/concepts/#quantified-path-patterns, and then googling for "Cypher Quantified Pattern Patterns" should find a lot more I'd expect.
For example, this is how you would do your 1. above:
MATCH path = (startUser:User {name:'Adam'})
             (()-[:Follows]->()-[:Likes]->())*
             (endUser:User)
RETURN path


Hi Alex, thanks for the answer. I went through the documents and found the quantified path pattern part only focused on one relationship. And the sample query you provided also didn't work from my side. The antlr parser with the newest cypher syntax couldn't recognize it as the correct syntax.
